# Why does webapps open another browser icon?

Tags: unity, webapps

When I open the BBC web app, it opens another window of Chromium despite me already having one open. The happens with all of my web apps. The image above will show you what I am talking about.

[image]

Comment: Does it happen for other Webapps too ?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: I am pretty sure this isn't intended behavior.

Comment: This was reported as a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-firefox-extension/+bug/1079967

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. It makes another icon so that you can easily go to the webapp. It opens another window because it has to have the webpage open in order to work. If you manually open a tab on the webpage of the app it should make an icon that takes you directly to that tab.

Comment: But why does it open two windows of chromium? can you disable this and make it just open a new tab in the chromium window i already have open?

Comment: Probably not without patching + rebuilding unity-webapps-runner, or persuading the developers that adding this as an option is a good idea. The former would probably be easier.

Answer (score 0):

To my eyes, this is a bug. It would be useful if you reported it on Launchpad. Here is how you can do it:

Hit Alt+F2, that will open the "Run a command" interface. Then type "apport-bug unity-webapps-bbcnews", hit Enter and simply follow the instructions.