# ubuntu webapps create multiple icons when opened

Tags: unity, 13.04, launcher, chromium, webapps

I recently installed chromium on ubuntu 13.04 and started using webapps. The problem is for every webapp open there is an icon for the webapp and an icon for chromium in my launcher.

For example if i have youtube,facebook and linkedin opened.Then I have youtube,facebook and linkedin icons alongside with 3 chromium icons filling up my launcher.I don't want those extra chromium icons.
Is there a way around this?

Comment: I got same same issue.
Did you find a solution?

Comment: I just stopped using webapps :D .. I have seen other people having the same issue but no one seems to have a solution for it ..

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/200794/why-does-webapps-open-another-browser-icon ?

Answer (score 0):

You are presented with a choice when the webapps are first utilised. You may either install the additional "features" (the Unity Quick Launcher icon) or not. This is supposed to be a shortcut of sort for most used web applications. Handy for tablets, phones, maybe not so much for a PC or desktop. It becomes a matter of personal preference to my way of thinking, but that is opinion, not a statement of fact. Given that, my choice is to use an extension for the browser (the Speed Dial) that provides fast access to all chosen sites.

YMMV here, as you may want those shortcuts in the launcher. They arrive there to speed access, but can become annoying (IMHO) if they take too much screen real-estate.

HTH. Have a nice day.

Comment: You didn't address the problem of the additional chromium icons though.

Comment: Can't replicate that behaviour in Chromium myself, but then I use a two-factor auth scheme and have disabled Google Sync. Not certain how this occurs without a conscious choice to install the webapp and its features.